# How To Filter Product By Category in Laravel or PHP

Tags: php, laravel

im trying to filter products by categories
for example look at this url
**http://127.0.0.1:8000/index?category=php,html,js**
the result it must the products that have php and html languages.
these are my tables

```
Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('title',100);
    $table->text('description');
    $table->text('cover');
    $table->text('file');
    $table->integer('user_id');
    $table->integer('price');
    $table->timestamps();
});
Schema::create('languages', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('title');
    $table->timestamps();
});
Schema::create('product_language', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->integer('product_id');
    $table->integer('technology_id');
});
```

[image: Product Module]

[image: Language Module]

[image: PrTe Module]

IndexController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\Product;
use App\Language;
use App\PrTe; //this is the pr_tes table module, which have (product and languages) Foreign Keys

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $Products = new PrTe;
        $Queries = [];
        $Columns = [
            'languages.title'            => 'category',
        ];
        $CategoryParameters = array_filter(explode(',',request('category')),function($value){
            return !is_null($value) && $value !== '';
        });
        $Products = $Products::join('products', 'pr_tes.product_id', '=', 'products.id')
                             ->join('languages', 'pr_tes.language_id', '=', 'languages.id');
                             
        foreach ($Columns as $Field => $Column) 
        {
            if(request()->has($Column) && request($Column) != null)
            {
                $Products = $Products->where($Field,request($Column));
                $Queries[$Column] = request($Column); 
            }
        }
        $Products = $Products->groupBy('products.id');
        $Products = $Products->paginate(5)->appends($Queries);
        return view('index',compact('Products'));
    }
}
```

*is this table design is good or not

Comment: Shouldn't `$table->integer('technology_id');` be `$table->integer('language_id');` to begin with? Also, what exactly is your question? Is it about the design (whether it's good or bad) or is there something wrong? Please review the question and provide helpful details.

Comment: You can use pivot for this type of table structures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First the relationship `language` should be `languages` since it is a hasMany.

The most `Laravel` way of doing this, is to use `whereHas()`. Something similar to this, instead of all the hoops your tried in your own solution. Utilizing when for only querying if categories are present.

```
$CategoryParameters = array_filter(explode(',', request('category')), function($value) {
    return !is_null($value) && $value !== '';
});

$products = Product::whereHas('languages', function ($query) use ($CategoryParameters) {
    $query->when(count($CategoryParameters), function ($query) use ($CategoryParameters) {
        $query->whereIn('title', $CategoryParameters);
    });
})->get();
```

The downside is `whereHas()` produces a not so fast exists SQL statement compared to the join solution. Since languages is programming languages, i do not believe performance will be a problem with this query any time soon. While the code being way more simple.